# Android Studio 3.0 - Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List'

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Trying to start a new Kotlin project with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 displays this error. Full trace:

> Error:Unable to find method
>   'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I've tried the first two options and the third-party plugins are left as default.

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Thu May 18 08:36:52 BST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I haven't touched any of these values myself, they're left as default. Creating a non-Kotlin new project does not have this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607224/com-android-build-gradle-api-basevariant-getoutputsljava-util-list)

Answer (score 202, accepted):

In my **build.gradle** changing

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'`

to

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'`

fixed this.

You can find the most recent version [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android).

Comment: Solved here! But the plugin is on version `1.1.2-3`, not on `1.1.2-4`, what I can do?

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim I'm not sure if this is the *right* answer, but when I went into Settings > Plugins and uninstalled the Kotlin plugin and restarted, it booted up with 1.1.2-4 installed. Weird, but possibly a step in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, just delete the plugin and voilá

Comment: i can confirm that this working on android studio 3.0 canary 3, upvoted

Comment: Strange, this happened to me now when I just downloaded Android studio 3. Luckily I ended up here to find the solution

Comment: This solution isn't working for me. I just imported an existing project into AS 3.0 Canary 4 that doesn't have Kotlin in it and it still occurs. Deleting the Kotlin plugin is not possible and disabling it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Max you're right. To downgrade the plug-in version, I did this. Now my kotlin plugin version is down to 1.1.3-2 from 1.2-M2, and now I my project is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me

Using the 8.4.0 version

```
 classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Java**

Just remove

> `classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'`

downgrade `butterknife`version to `8.4.0`

> `classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'`

Don't forget to remove

`apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'`

from app level build gradle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/kotlin-issues.html) in Android Studio Preview 3.0:

> If you see this error, it's possible you have a pre-existing version of the Kotlin plugin that is incompatible with the new Android Plugin for Gradle that's in Android Studio 3.0. The solution is to delete the old Kotlin plugin.
>
> Open your project-level `build.gradle` file and locate `ext.kotlin_version`. It should be 1.1.2-4 (or higher). If it shows an older version, you need to delete the old Kotlin plugin so it does not obstruct the version included with Android Studio 3.0.
>
> On Windows, it should be located at
>
> `C:\Users\user_name\AndroidStudio_version\config\plugins\Kotlin\`
>
> On Mac, look in
>
> `~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio_version/Kotlin/`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was caused because we were applying *butterknife-gradle-plugin*. Upgrading to 8.8.1 didn't fix the issue, but removing it certainly did.

The *build.gradle* belongs to the application, so I don't even know why we are using that plugin (I'm new to the project)

Answer (score 1):

Update your kotlin version to the latest:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4' //currently it's the latest version
```

Then you may face some more errors, so before syncing again, make sure that your `buildToolsVersion` is "26.0.2" or higher.