# unable to configure Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i am unable to configure Kotlin in my android studio. getting error
Error:Unable to find method'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043185/7134908) answer might help you.If you having some other problem then please post your code also

Comment: Which kotlin version you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updated to Android Studio 3.0. Getting a "Kotlin not configured" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170118/updated-to-android-studio-3-0-getting-a-kotlin-not-configured-error)

Answer (score 0):

That problem very often occurs when you use wrong version of Kotlin. For now current version in your build.gradle should bee 
"ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'".