# Updated to Android Studio 3.0. Getting a "Kotlin not configured" error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I just updated to Android Studio 3.0 and I'm getting this error with an existing project:

> Kotlin not configured

When I go to *Tools>Kotlin>Configure Kotlin in Project*, I get an error saying "*no configurators available*". Also get the error below with the red java:

[image]

I've also tried:

- Restarting
- Clean and Rebuild
- Invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: Try a clean build from CLI, it worked for me: close Android Studio and run `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` then start Android Studio again.

Comment: This worked for me. You should add it as an answer

Comment: thanks @m3dw3 . It worked for me. I faced this issue after changing my  .gradle directory path.

Comment: In my newly created project (via Android Studio 3.2.1 stable), I had following kotlin version defined in project's build.gradle: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11' '1.2.71'`. I removed the second version and so it looked like this `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'`.

Comment: `File -> Sync Project with Gradle files` worked for me ...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I first tried with invalidate cache/ restart option but it doesn't help me.

When I updated Kotlin to 1.1.60 in project's gradle file, problem is solved.

Also, use this in app's gradle for stdlib

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.60"
```

instead of

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.60"
```

Comment: A few lines of context to know where the line need to be replaced would have been nice.

Comment: I tried this which I thought resolved the issue. However, when I reverted to my original *implementation* `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"` the error was still resolved. I must of just needed to have the gradle file re0run.

Comment: Thanks!
Removing jre7 from dependency helped me to sync and finally build project with a new Kotlin version.

Answer (score 40):

In Android Studio, click on File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... , then select "Invalidated and Restart". This solved my problem.

Comment: This answer is not specific to Mac. It also worked on my Windows machine.

Comment: This answer works for me. It should be the approved one

Answer (score 13):

This error also occurs if you have the `mavenCentral()` repository missing in `allprojects`.
Your `build.gradle (:app)` should contain at least this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

`jcenter()` would work as well (for now), but that repository reached end-of-life and shouldn't be used any more.

Answer (score 4):

Closing and restarting Android Studio works for me in that case. Important is that there are no other projects opened in Android Studio before you close it. I suspect that closing Android Studio with multiple opened project windows sometimes messes up the configuration especially after plugin upgrades etc.

Answer (score 3):

## Important Update

#### You should check JDK version before setting config

[Kotlin gradle config](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies) page has detailed information about this.

### Step 1

Check kotlin version in project level gradle file.

> ```
> classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
> ```
>
> ### For `kotlin_version '1.2.x'` Use `jdk` NOT `jre`

### Step 2

Check JDK version in **File > Project Structure**

[image: sc]

**Or** check in `build.gradle`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

If no JDK version is set in Project Structure, then choose by Android Studio version

- JDK version is 1.7 for Android Studio Version < 2.2.1
- JDK version is 1.8 for Android Studio Version < 2.2.1

**Because Android Studio is bundled with jdk 1.8 since 2.2.1 version.**

**You have 3 options of kotlin stdlib, choose according JDK version**

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version" //jdk_version == 1.8
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" //jdk_version == 1.7
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" // jdk_version is < 1.7
```

> ### if `kotlin version is'1.1.x'` Use jre NOT jdk

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version" // or jre8
```

#### Update Kotlin Version?

You can update Kotlin version from **Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Updates**

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated since 1.2.0 and should be replaced with kotlin-stdlib-**jdk7**

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 3):

A common reason of the "Kotlin Not Configured" message is **an internal Android Studio exception due to a bad plugin**.
In order to fix that you should disable the bad plugin.

When such plugin crash occurs, on the "Wellcome screen" you'll see a small notification (see illustration image) where you can click it and disable the bad plugin:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue recently... when I updated to Android Studio 3.1 .

I did a few things to fix this.

1. First I updated the Kotlin version in my app gradle file and added

   ```
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.31"
   ```

   in my app gradle file. But this alone didn't fix it.
2. Then uninstalled the kotlin plugin from settings, restarted Android Studio and installed it again.

**EDIT :**

This is my project gradle file

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
    }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.31"

   }
 }

allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
      google()
   }
}
```

And this is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {

   compileSdkVersion 27

   buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

   defaultConfig {
       ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    sourceSets {
         main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
     }

     kapt { generateStubs = true }


}
repositories {
     ...
}


dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.31"
    ...
    ...

 }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: A few lines of context to know where the line goes would have been nice.

Answer (score 2):

just delete .idea folder from project,and run android studio again, it will resolve KOTLIN NOT CONFIGURED issue.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions solved my problem. I ended up figuring out that the problem lied in the google services version. Just update it to the latest.

Top level gradle at dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after the update of Android Studio and plugins, I could create new projects, but my old projects were having "Gradle Sync Issues".

The solution was in File/Project Structure.../App/Dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

And then I just updated the Kotlin version in my project build.gradle:

From:

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'

To:

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'

Then I tried Sync again.

Obs: You can check your Kotlin version in Tools/Kotlin/Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all above solutions but non of them works for me.

Then finally I got success with below solution, so it may helpful for some one like me.

1. Delele all `.iml` files (in root project, libraries and modules)
2. Rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to update Android studio from version 3.4.1. to 3.5 and it resolved the *kotlin not configured* error.

Answer (score 1):

Delete ***.AndroidStudio3.6*** folder in ***C:\Users\Username*** and re-open Android studio works for me

Answer (score 1):

The only fix for me was adding

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

in build.gradle (:app)

Answer (score 0):

One other point to check is version of your Gradle in `gradle-wrapper.properties`, if you use one.

Make sure that 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Has version 4.1 or higher.

You may also have the following in your `build.gradle`:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1'
    distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}
```

Where Gradle version is lower that 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Though I see that the question already has answers that work, one might also try the following solution.

Right click on the file name (Main.kt) -> Run 'Main.kt'.

This will download a gradle file from the gradle.org website.

Wait for it to unzip. The errors were cleared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a broken update of one of the plugins I've used. Check your error logs from Android Studio this will lead you to what is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Simply Create a new Activity and select its language to kotlin Android studio Automatically configured kotlin for you.