# Gradle Sync Issue Kotlin after Android 3.1 Stable Update

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-plugin, kotlin-extension, android-studio-3.1

Hey after updating Android Studio to 3.1 Stable version i am getting following error to all my projects. Any help will be appreciated.

> Could not download kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.3-2): No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: I unchecked the offline checkbox, while sync project always running Metadata of https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3-2/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3-2-sources.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its Kotlin version related issue.
First try to update your kotling version. I guess latest version is `1.2.31`

The version of Kotlin to use is usually defined as the kotlin_version property:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

For details: `https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html`

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49512570/3315959) . One of the key is to update the kotlin plugin from settings in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

try this
Android studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, Silly Mistake figure out just **Uncheck Offline checkbox from Gradle settings**. :) Download all dependencies by build gradle online.