# cannot start android on intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am new to android development. I am trying to start a `"hello world"` project for an android app following the google android fundamentals course.

I believe i have the android plugin correctly installed. I keep getting the

> error:  Failed to resolve:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.3.21

The code in my hello world app is:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.21"
    //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

Comment: I found the Fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170118/updated-to-android-studio-3-0-getting-a-kotlin-not-configured-error

Comment: `jre7` should be replaced with `jdk7` i think

Answer (score 15):

You need to replace `jre` by `jdk` as suggested by [EpicPandaForce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce):

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace jre by jdk.

Previous:

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

After Replace:

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```