# Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, butterknife

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.7.0'
    }
}


      android{
            compileSdkVersion = 26  
            buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion = 16
            targetSdkVersion = 26

        }
    ...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = "newApkName.apk"
        }
    }
}
```

How to solve issue:

> ```
> Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
> ```
>
> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>       Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync
>   project (requires network)
>       The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>   processes (requires restart)
>       Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of
>   Gradle requested by the project.
>       In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer so that the question doesn't look like unanswered for the people who are looking to offer help.

Comment: I found the easiest way is to "remove butterknife", it may cost you few minutes, but with butterknife, you'll spend weeks to pass compiling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same error with gradle syncing, specifically tied to butterknife, my solution was solved via

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/963#issuecomment-339545297

tldr in your project build file...

```
buildscript{
 repositories {
   //other repos will likely exist here like jcenter and mavenCentral

   //add this closure
   maven {
    url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
   }
  }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.7.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    //change your version to 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT
     classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    //.. other project level dependencies 
   }
 }
}
```

Also make sure your allproject includes

```
allproject{
  repositories{
    maven {
      //this
      url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
   }
 }
```

And then the none butterknife related issue was upping my `buildToolsVersions` to `"26.0.2"` in your app build file

UPDATE 4/19/2018
Have since parted ways with butterknife as it has since caused more issues than any other 3rd party I've used. Besides, with full Kotlin support, butterknife isn't necessary

Comment: In my library project (R2 imports) this comment helped me:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/963#issuecomment-342547601

Answer (score 0):

seems that issue is not in `app/build.gradle` , but in `butterknife-gradle-plugin`

Solved by removing `butterknife-gradle-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Based on ElliotM's answer:

- Kotlin 1.2.10
- Gradle 3.0.1
- Build tools version 27.0.3
- apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
- apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
- apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
- apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

In my library project this comment helped me (R2 imports):
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/963#issuecomment-342547601

project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}
```

module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

This way you can use the

```
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to upgrade gradle in my project

from : `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4`

to : `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3`