# Chat with Firestore crashes with NullPointerException on RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am pretty new to RecyclerView, so please forgive me if the resolution is very simple. I digged around but no luck so I need guidance.
Adapting the Chat with FirebaseUI with Firestore grabbing the code from https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android.

Here is the main code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.util.ui.ImeHelper;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

/**
 * Class demonstrating how to setup a {@link RecyclerView} with an adapter while taking sign-in
 * states into consideration. Also demonstrates adding data to a ref and then reading it back using
 * the {@link FirestoreRecyclerAdapter} to build a simple chat app.
 * <p>
 * For a general intro to the RecyclerView, see <a href="https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html">Creating
 * Lists</a>.
 */
public class BlaBlaBlaChat extends AppCompatActivity
        implements FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
    private static final String TAG = "BlaBlaBlaChat";

    private static final CollectionReference sChatCollection =
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("chats");
    /** Get the last 50 chat messages ordered by timestamp . */
    private static final Query sChatQuery = sChatCollection.orderBy("timestamp").limit(50);

    static {
        FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    }

    @BindView(R.id.messagesList)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @BindView(R.id.sendButton)
    Button mSendButton;

    @BindView(R.id.messageEdit)
    EditText mMessageEdit;

    @BindView(R.id.emptyTextView)
    TextView mEmptyListMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ireland_chat);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ImeHelper.setImeOnDoneListener(mMessageEdit, new ImeHelper.DonePressedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDonePressed() {
                onSendClick();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (isSignedIn()) { attachRecyclerViewAdapter(); }
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth auth) {
        mSendButton.setEnabled(isSignedIn());
        mMessageEdit.setEnabled(isSignedIn());

        if (isSignedIn()) {
            attachRecyclerViewAdapter();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.signing_in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            auth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(new BlaBlaBlaChatSignInHolder(this));
        }
    }

    private boolean isSignedIn() {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null;
    }

    private void attachRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = newAdapter();

        // Scroll to bottom on new messages
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.sendButton)
    public void onSendClick() {
        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        String name = "User " + uid.substring(0, 6);

        onAddMessage(new BlaBlaBlaChatAbstractExtend(name, mMessageEdit.getText().toString(), uid));

        mMessageEdit.setText("");
    }

    protected RecyclerView.Adapter newAdapter() {
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<BlaBlaBlaChatAbstractExtend> options =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<BlaBlaBlaChatAbstractExtend>()
                        .setQuery(sChatQuery, BlaBlaBlaChatAbstractExtend.class)
                        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .build();

        return new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<BlaBlaBlaChatAbstractExtend, BlaBlaBlaChatHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public BlaBlaBlaChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new BlaBlaBlaChatHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.message, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BlaBlaBlaChatHolder holder, int position, @NonNull BlaBlaBlaChatAbstractExtend model) {
                holder.bind(model);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                // If there are no chat messages, show a view that invites the user to add a message.
                mEmptyListMessage.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        };
    }

    protected void onAddMessage(BlaBlaBlaChatAbstractExtend chat) {
        sChatCollection.add(chat).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write message", e);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.balblabla.BlaBlaBlaChat">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/start_chatting" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messagesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/ireland_chat_message" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEdit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:text="@string/send" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

From logcat:

```
01-12 18:07:36.443 31599-31599/com.example.carlo.blablabla E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.carlo.blablabla/com.example.carlo.blablabla.BlaBlaBlaChat}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.carlo.blablabla.BlaBlaBlaChat.onCreate(BlaBlaBlaChat.java:73)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6681)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
01-12 18:07:36.715 31599-31599/com.example.carlo.blablabla E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.carlo.blablabla, PID: 31599
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.carlo.blablabla/com.example.carlo.blablabla.BlaBlaBlaChat}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.carlo.blablabla.BlaBlaBlaChat.onCreate(BlaBlaBlaChat.java:73)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6681)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Gradle Project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle APP:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blablabla.albalbalb"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.3'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    // Testing dependencies

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The code is just a cut/paste from the Github code, but something went wrong.

Comment: He's using [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) (a view binder library) for that @FrankvanPuffelen . But I think he might have done something wrong there, because the error does show that `mRecyclerView` hasn't been initialized

Comment: Can you also show us your `build.gradle` files? For both project and app modules

Comment: Updated it into the case

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't add the ButterKnife library to your project correctly.

In your app's build.gradle file, you must add the annotationProcessor after `implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"` like this:
`annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1"`

And in your project's build.gradle file add the ButterKnife plugin to your buildscript:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: app's gives Error:Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.< Restart / resync not solving it

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46955396)

Comment: Rosario, after deleting apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife' is working now. Thumbs up for ye!

Comment: Less than 15 bud.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mRecyclerView` which is never initialized and that's why you are getting that error. In order to solve this, you must first initialize it before you use it. Assuming that the id of your `RecyclerView` is `recycler_view`, please use the following code in your `onCreate()` method:

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

Comment: As Rosário commented, Butterknife is supposed to take care of this because of the `@BindView(R.id.messagesList)` annotation. Somehow that is not being picked up, or it happens later (I'm not a Butterknife user myself).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. BTW if I initialize mRecyclerView on onCreate it does it         RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messagesList);
        //
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));  But mRecycleView is not updated outside onCreate And fails when called in onStart()

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, in this case Rosário's answer could solve the problem. I'm also not a Butterknife user and that's why I think I missed that annotation. Thank you!